# sed not working as expected, removing special character from middle of string

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have a file 'test' with the contents:

```
sa!ve
hel!lo
te!st
te!ve
help!
please!
```

I'd like to remove any exclamation mark which is in between two lowercase letters. So the results should be:

```
save
hello
test
teve
help!
please!
```

I've tried `cat test | sed 's/\([:lower:]\)\!\([:lower:]\)/\1\2/g'` and alpha/alphanum but strange, it's only working for the word 'hel!lo' and nothing else, my results have been:

```
sa!ve
hello
te!st
te!ve
help!
please!
```

Not sure why it's not working for the other words.

Comment: Useless Use Of Cat warning. Consider `sed '...' test`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is you're using the character class incorrectly. `[:lower:]` *is the name of the character set*, so you'd actually use it like so `[[:lower:]]`.

Therefore the correct sed expression is:

```
cat test |  sed 's/\([[:lower:]]\)\!\([[:lower:]]\)/\1\2/g'
```

Which works as expected.

Here's the output I get:

```
save
hello
test
teve
help!
please!
```

So you can think of `[:lower:]` as *shorthand* for `a-z`, so when creating a character on the fly, this becomes `[[:lower:]]`. It's a tricky one that a lot of people get bitten by the first couple of times around.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Works as expected. Good to know there is a difference, live and learn.

Answer (score 1):

You are using character class so `[:lower:]` would any single character within the square bracket. In your input where only `l`(which is present in the character class `:lower:`) is getting matched so that it's getting replaced.

Change it to character range `[a-z]` for matching any lower case alphabet within the range.

```
cat test | sed 's/\([a-z]\)\!\([a-z]\)/\1\2/g'
```

Comment: Or, better, `[[:lower:]]`, which is locale save.

Comment: Hmm, works. Thanks for the guidance, still not sure why it doesn't work. I'll have to look into what using a character class vs character range/set is.

Comment: See [POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03) (RE Bracket Expressions / character classes).